# Problem with the first character of the binary file while reading it in a C file

Tags: c, linux, binaryfiles

I am trying to read a binary file and its content.

```
/*aoObj.fb is the pointer of the file (e.x. FILE *fp)*/

char ch;
aoObj.fp = fopen(aoObj.f_name, "rb");

if (aoObj.fp == NULL)

      {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

        /* /\*list all strings *\/ */
        printf("\n\nThe content of the file: \n");

        while ((ch = fgetc(aoObj.fp)) != EOF)
          printf("%c", ch);

        fclose(aoObj.fp);
        (void) opt_free(&aoObj);
        return 0;
}
```

But I am facing issues when I print the content of thi file because only the first character of the input isn't printed ok, as follows:

[image]

May I know why this is happening ?

***EDIT: All the variables which are being read are declared as STRINGS***

Comment: Maybe UTF-8 BOM?

Comment: Change `char ch` to `int ch` and I guess you could use `getc()` too. See if it solves.

Comment: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: Nope, neither getc() nor the int char didn't solve the issue

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `aoObj`   This struct is not defined, so, either post the definition or removed those references from your question.

Comment: regarding: `(void) opt_free(&aoObj);`  do you think this has anything to do with the problem?  If not, then it should not be included

Comment: Albion Shala, "because only the first character of the input isn't printed ok," --> What did you expect?  Without posting how the file is made, this posts lacks important information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP states the file contents are 'binary' not 'text'  Therefore, accessing the file should be via the I/O operators made for binary files,

Suggest:

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

Since the data read from the 'binary' file is NOT ascii characters, it is an 'error' to try to print those 'binary' characters with the 'output format conversion' specifier: `%c`.

Suggest:

```
printf( "%02x\n", ch );
```

Note: the `%02x` so a leading nibble of 0x0 will be printed rather than suppressed.

When the code is corrected to use: `fread()` rather than `fgetc()` the declaration of `ch` can/should be `unsigned char ch;`  so no need to change that to `int ch;`

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. is missing a `main()` function and the passing of the parameter: `f_name` so does not link
4. properly checks for an error when opening the input file
5. uses the returned value from `fread()` to 'assume' EOF, however, it may be instructive (and for robust code) to check the value of `errno` just to assure there was no other error.
6. documents why each header file is included

Note: the proposed code is not very efficient as it only reads a single byte at a time rather than a whole buffer full of bytes

Note: the proposed code will output one byte contents (in hex) on a single line.  You might want to modify that to output several bytes contents (in hex) before moving to a new line.

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // FILE, fopen(), perror(), printf(), fclose()
                      // fread()
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

void myfunc( char *f_name )
{
    unsigned char ch;
    FILE *fp = fopen( f_name, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* /\*list all strings *\/ */
    printf("\n\nThe content of the file: \n");

    size_t bytesRead;
    while ( ( bytesRead = fread( &ch, 1, 1, fp ) ) == 1 )
    {
        printf("%02x\n", ch);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Note  that `printf("%02x\n", ch);` may print `FFFFFFFF` when `ch = -1;`    Suggest `char ch;` --> `unsigned char ch;`

Comment: I do mean -1.  When `ch` is _signed_., it typically has values in the [-128 ... 127]  range.  If `ch` had the value of 0x81 or 129, is is likely an _unsigned_ `char` and pose no trouble here.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica,  As usual, your correct.  BTW: I modified the code to have `char ch = (char)0x81` and it output `ffffff81`, so any negative value would be a problem.  I'll fix the answer.